# Fulltext "title" search in 1M rows

Tags: mysql

There is a 3.3GB `articles` Myisam table with following fields: `id, title, perma, body, date`
primary key: `id`
fulltext index: `title`

It has 1,110,000 rows. After I did this:

```
SET GLOBAL key_buffer_size = 2000*1024*1024; LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE articles INDEX(title);
```

I can't get enough performance.

You can see execution times of several samples below:

```
<9.5381848812103>
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE perma,title,body, MATCH(title) AGAINST('flowers for children' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS sort
FROM articles  WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('flowers for children' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY sort DESC LIMIT 30;

<12.734259843826>
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE perma,title,body, MATCH(title) AGAINST('how to play basketball' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS sort
FROM articles  WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('how to play basketball' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY sort DESC LIMIT 30;

<4.4655818939209>
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE perma,title,body, MATCH(title) AGAINST('kill a bird and eat it' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS sort
FROM articles  WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('kill a bird and eat it' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY sort DESC LIMIT 30;

<16.268588066101>
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE perma,title,body, MATCH(title) AGAINST('avoid back pain' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS sort
FROM articles  WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('avoid back pain' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY sort DESC LIMIT 30;

<12.553371906281>
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE perma,title,body, MATCH(title) AGAINST('computer' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS sort
FROM articles  WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('computer' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY sort DESC LIMIT 30;
```

Any suggestions to make the execution time better?

Comment: I have no good suggestion other than using a dedicated search engine such as Lucene. What's the performance like without the "ORDER BY" clause?

Comment: Much faster without "ORDER BY"

Comment: How many items in the results?

Comment: For the examples I've given, 4k, 6k, 1k, 20k, 4k respectively.

Comment: People! Is my question so stupid? If it is I'm sorry, but I need a little more help please!

Comment: Bruno Silva already gave you the only correct answer I know of:  Use a dedicated search engine instead of the built in full text search (performance will definitely be an issue going the route you are as your data set grows).

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using "IN BOOLEAN MODE"? I noticed that you aren't using it for the functions its operators offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your first query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE perma,title,body,
MATCH(title) AGAINST('flowers for children' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS sort
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('flowers for children' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY sort DESC LIMIT 30;
```

You might need to refactor this

First, pick up the keys and the sort value

```
SELECT id,MATCH(title) AGAINST ('flowers for children' IN BOOLEAN MODE) sort
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('flowers for children' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This query will result in a 800M temp table

Next, limit it to 30 highest sort values

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT id,MATCH(title) AGAINST ('flowers for children' IN BOOLEAN MODE) sort
    FROM articles
    WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('flowers for children' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) AA
ORDER BY sort DESC LIMIT 30;
```

OK now a 720 byte temp table

Finally, `LEFT JOIN` those 30 rows to the `articles` table

```
SELECT
    B.perma,B.title,B.body,A.sort
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT id,MATCH(title) AGAINST ('flowers for children' IN BOOLEAN MODE) sort
        FROM articles
        WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('flowers for children' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ) AA
    ORDER BY sort DESC LIMIT 30
) A LEFT JOIN articles B USING (id);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thank you for your effort and help but the last part(4th code block) gives me an error: SQL Error (1146): Table 'article.b' doesn't exist. article is the database name. 3rd code block works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try just using the default "IN NORMAL MODE" as opposed to "IN BOOLEAN MODE".

I'm not sure if there is any particular reason why you chose "IN BOOLEAN MODE".  I noticed that you weren't using any of the operators that "IN BOOLEAN MODE" offers. Also, because of the large data set, you shouldn't have to worry about the 50% threshold.

I'm suggesting this because "IN NORMAL MODE" will also sort results by relevance without the need of "ORDER BY".  That is according to the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).

Oh, and unless you have changed the minimum word size, the shortest words included in a "FULLTEXT INDEX" are 4 letters long. So the "for" in your "AGAINST(...)" would be unnecessary, unless the min word size was changed.